# get_posts() function does not honor correct post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, get-posts

I'm fetching all posts of a specific custom post type like below.

```
print_r(ANCR_POST_TYPE);

$announcements = array();
$announcement_posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => ANCR_POST_TYPE, // Post type is set to "announcer"
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));

print_r($announcement_posts);
```

But the `get_posts()` function returns posts which are not of type `ANCR_POST_TYPE`

```
announcer
Array
    (
        [0] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 104
                [post_author] => 1
                [post_date] => 2023-07-07 18:15:23
                [post_date_gmt] => 2023-07-07 18:15:23
                [post_content] => This is an event
                [post_title] => Event
                [post_excerpt] => 
                [post_status] => publish
                [comment_status] => open
                [ping_status] => closed
                [post_password] => 
                [post_name] => event
                [to_ping] => 
                [pinged] => 
                [post_modified] => 2023-07-07 18:15:23
                [post_modified_gmt] => 2023-07-07 18:15:23
                [post_content_filtered] => 
                [post_parent] => 0
                [guid] => https://example.com/?post_type=tribe_events&#038;p=104
                [menu_order] => 0
                [post_type] => tribe_events  <----- posts of type "tribe_events" is retreived instead of type "announcer"
                [post_mime_type] => 
                [comment_count] => 0
                [filter] => raw
            )
    
    )
```

This is seen only on the tags archive page of "tribe_events" post type.

Any idea on when this could happen?

Comment: are you using a `pre_get_posts` filter in your sites code? Functions on that filter can modify parameters that are fed into `WP_Query` and its wrapper functions such as `get_posts`

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell, no, this was reported by one my plugin's user. This is observed in "the events calendar" plugin's post type page. As you said it is possible that the plugin has a filter to tweak the post type. I'll look into it's source and update.

Comment: it's very possible, `pre_get_posts` filters sometimes do this if they don't have enough conditions/checks to prevent leakage. You could use the suppress filters option but then that means it's impossible to filter/extend that query and you break compatibility with caching plugins and other things, e.g. no more elastic search support. My suspicion is that the filter the user has doesn't check if it's the main query or not

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a `pre_get_posts` action that doesn't have the proper conditions/checks.

For example:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) : void {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'tribe_events' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'tribe_events' );
    }
} );
```

Likewise if this was a page template and not a post archive they might have this in their theme template to force it to show only posts of that type:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) : void {
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'tribe_events' );
} );
```

Both of these would cause the problem you described. Fixing them will be specific to that specific callback though.Checking `$query->is_main_query()` may help.

### How to Fix It?

Fundamentally this isn't a problem with your plugin, it's something in the users site code, and they will need to find and identify this. The usual process of elimination of disabling things and checking will help, as will a search and code review of any `pre_get_posts` callbacks.

Comment: I agree that the issue in question happened likely due to failure in targeting the right query. However, it should be noted that `get_posts()` by default [sets `suppress_filters` to `true`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#parameters), i.e. it suppresses all (pre-query) *filters* like `posts_search` and `posts_where`. Secondly, `pre_get_posts` is an action hook and not a filter, hence it still runs even when using `get_posts()`.

Comment: that's not true in newer versions of WordPress, suppress filters default value was changed to false on `get_posts, so that only applies for much older versions. I've removed that paragraph though to avoid confusion

Comment: What newer versions are they , because to my knowledge, `get_posts()` has always been suppressing filters by default - it's like that a decade ago ([example](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L1706C3-L1706C29)) and still like that in version [6.2.2](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2392C3-L2392C30), and even the [`trunk` version](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/e62dfe87ced93cdf8686669823245dd308da6395/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2416C3-L2416C30) as of writing.

Comment: it seems in WP 6.1 core will still cache results even when `suppress_filters` is set to true https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/10/07/improvements-to-wp_query-performance-in-6-1/

Comment: Yes, it doesn't suppress caching.. and not all filters are suppressed, either - e.g. `posts_pre_query` (filters the posts array before the query takes place) is not suppressed, but `posts_results` (this runs after querying the database) is suppressed.

Comment: The argument which can suppress caching, or [determine whether cached results should be returned](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L3162-L3204), is `cache_results`, so @AakashChakravarthy could try using that argument, i.e. `'cache_results' => false`, to see if caching is the culprit..